# How can I connect to two different projects in Google BigQuery in Python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to connect to two different BigQuery projects in Python, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have two JSON keys, both of which work when run separately, but I want to run them together so I can do a join from two different projects.

Here is my code:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:\\Users\\zuser\\Desktop\\JSON_Keys\\firstjsonkey.json')
credentials_2ndproject = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('C:\\Users\\zuser\\Desktop\\JSON_Keys\\2ndjsonkey.json')

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project="project1")
client_2ndproject = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials_2ndproject, project="project2")
```

This code is accepted.

Here is where there is a problem:

```
sales = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

I know this will bring in one project, but how do I bring in the second if my sql query has a join?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not add the permission for one of your service accounts to access the table in the other project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a SQL query with joins from both tables from both the projects. Execute it as a single query. You need not to create different big query clients instead

```
sameple_query = f"""select * from {{project1}}.{{dataset1}}.{{table1}} left join select * from {{project2}}.{{dataset2}}.{{table2}}"""
```

#### 1. use a service account with permissions on both projects to create the credentials object and big query client creation.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service_account_key_for_both_projects_bigquery_access.json')
bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)
bqclient.query(sample_query).result().to_dataframe()
```

### Note: result() will wait for the query to complete and then return the dataframe.

Or

#### 2. If your user has access to both projects, you can use the same query with bigquery client from any of the project.

```
# getting the credentials and project details for gcp project
    credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
# creating a big query clients
    bqclient = bigquery.Client(
        credentials=credentials,
        project=your_project_id
    )
```